# how to pass props one page to another page via react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In my React app I'm using react-router-dom. In `App.js` I have set my routes. There I have three components: `/home`, `/customerinfo` and `/success`.

In the home component I have a button. What I want is that when I press the button, the `customerinfo` component will load in full page and I want the state of the `home` component in the `customerinfo` component. This is what my `Route` looks like:

```
<Route
  path="/customerInfo"
  render={props => <CustomerInfo {...props} />}
/>
```

But I don't have access of the state of the `home` component in `App.js`, so it's not working.

How can I get the state of the `home` component in `customerinfo`?

I'm new in React. Please help me.

Comment: Hi @Mustakin, could you add a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with the code you have at the moment? That way it will be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi @AxelJunes . Ok I am adding sandbox. Please wait ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use redux to pass data for complex application.

But if you want to stick around using react only then you could pass data using props to `Redirect` Component.

When `CustomerInfo` button is clicked data from `home` Controller is passed down to `customerInfo` component.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />

        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/customerinfo" component={CustomerInfo} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false,
    data: 'data passed through home route to customer info route'
  };
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      redirect: true
    })
  }
  render () {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/customerinfo',
        state: { data: this.state.data }
      }} />
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Home</h2>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>CustomerInfo</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

function CustomerInfo({ location }) {
  console.log(location)
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{location.state.data}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Yes @tarzen chugh you are right.I just want to pass the state.So this is the best way.Thank you so much ....